Multiple commands produce error in Xcode 15.3
I have been stuck on this bug for quite a while now so any help would be appreciated. When I try to Archive my Flutter app after Build, I keep getting the following build errors:

Multiple commands produce '/Users/vladrabets/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glcckwmfvouzcwbashuiinywfldz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle'


Multiple commands produce '/Users/vladrabets/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glcckwmfvouzcwbashuiinywfldz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'

I have tried solution that have been recommended on other stack overflow questions such as deleting certain files from the [CP] Copy Pods Resources and upgrading pods Minimum Deployments to iOS 12.0, but nothing seems to be working. Could someone please help me I'm really lost.

If you have widgets, they have deployment target iOS 14. I suggest to use SPM, instead of cocoapods. They doesn't have such problem when you have several targets in project with different deployment target.

You can add this below mentioned code in your podfile and again hit pod install command to check.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'GTMSessionFetcher'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES'] = 'GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle'
      end
    end
  end
end


Tried, it doesn't work.
